# How to make check-boxes which have option to select all in GWT?

Tags: checkbox, gwt, smartgwt, gxt

I am developing GWT app where I should use check-boxes. But I should have an option to select all checkboxes(like this example):

[image].

Which GWT widget should I use?

EDIT: This is my method which is used to retrieve data that should be in check boxes

```
 @Override
    protected RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole>> getDataProxy() {
        return new RpcProxy<PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole>>() {

            @Override
            protected void load(Object loadConfig, AsyncCallback<PagingLoadResult<GwtAccessRole>> callback) {
                GWT_ACCESS_ROLE_SERVICE.findByUserId((PagingLoadConfig) loadConfig,
                        currentSession.getSelectedAccount().getId(),
                        userId,
                        callback);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What code creates the checkboxes that you have in the image?

Comment: No, no this image is just example, I am getting data from RPC asynchronous methods...I used Simple Check Boxes in other situation, but now I need that option to select all check boxes...I have edited question to see my code for retrieving data from database...

Comment: Same two questions: What have you tried, and what code creates the checkboxes?

Comment: I think the image is from a JSE app, so we can assume it as desired result for the GWT app.

Comment: what are trying to achieve..please specify correctly and image is not showing in your post.

Comment: I want to find proper checkbox widget which has option for selecting all checkboxes at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

- `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Tree` with custom `TreeItem`.

or

- `com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellTree` with custom `Cell`.